# Windows Custom sounds events

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, desktop-customization, virtual-desktop, sound-editing

Hello so heres what Im trying to do, Im trying to replace all of the built in windows sounds with sounds from Legend of Zelda.  I want to add sounds for when you press the CTRL+WIN+Right/LeftArrows to switch virtual desktops.  I know that I need to modify Registry values like this [Windows custom sound events](https://superuser.com/questions/678019/windows-custom-sound-events) 
But Specifically, How do I add this for when you switch desktops?